# How to get the nearby docs in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that will save the user's location into Firebase, I need to get the nearby users according to the current user, I didn't need to run the filtering part in the app I need to send the user location and get it
(I checked the geoflutterfire but looks like it was deprected and getting version solving issue with firestore)

```
  Future<bool> markLocationAsSeen(LatLng latLng, String petId) async {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      missingPetsCollection
          .doc(id)
          .collection(FireStoreConstants.pathLocationMarkers)
          .add({
        "userId": Get.find<SessionManager>().getUserFirebaseId(),
        "location": GeoPoint(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),
        "createdAt": DateTime.now()
      });
      return true;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      Logger().e(e);
      return false;
      // TODO
    }
  }
```